# Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()

Tags: swift

I am working on a new view controller for my project and I get the error message "Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type 'String?'" when moving a new LabelRow in Eureka using Swift 4.2... any ideas what could be causing this error, why it happens and how I can fix this? Thanks in advance!

The problem code line is marked.

class SettingsCacheManagerViewController: FormViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "Data Usage"
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never // We do not want large title display on secondary view controllers.

    guard let cachedVideos = SSRSettings.CacheSettings.shared.CurrentCachedVideos else {
        self.form +++ Section(footer: "Downloaded its,s.")
        return
    }

    form +++ Section(footer: "A footer")
```

This is what I want to add, but cannot add it:

```
    Section <<< LabelRow { row in
    let dataConsumptionInMB = Double(SSRSettings.CacheSettings.shared.CurrentDataConsumptionForMonth ?? 0) / 1_000_000.0

    row.title = "Current Period"
    row.value = "\(String(format: "%.2f", dataConsumptionInMB)) MB / \(DATA_COMSUMPTION_HARD_LIMIT / 1_000_000) MB" //100 MB
    {
```

///// Rest of code
        }

```
    let rows = cachedVideos.map { item -> LabelRow in
        let video = allVideos[item.key]!

        return LabelRow(video.id) { row in
            row.title = video.title
            row.value = "\(String(format: "%.2f", Double(item.value.totalBytesStored) / 1_000_000.0)) MB"
        }
    }

    self.form
        +++ MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: []) { section in
           // This needs to be here...
            section.append(contentsOf: rows)
    }
}
}
```

}

Comment: On which line do you get the error?